# Stuck in "Creating Liferay plugin project..."

Tags: java, ant, liferay

Title says it all. Installed Ant (it's working, already checked), JDK 8, Liferay Portal 7, and downloaded the Liferay Plugins SDK. I already edited the build.properties, and set the "app.server.parent.dir" to the absolute direction of my Liferay server. I'm working in a W10 x64 environment.

Everything seems to be working well, except because I get stuck when greating a new Liferay Plugin Project, which is needed to develop portlets and so on.

It just doesn't give any error message, nor make the progress bar advance. It just gets stuck. When I cancel the operation, I can check the log in my workspace, whichs states the following:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.launching 4 120 2017-10-03 18:48:10.233
>   !MESSAGE Error logged from Ant UI:  !STACK 0 java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.launchConfigurations.RemoteAntBuildListener$ServerConnection.run(RemoteAntBuildListener.java:94)
>
> !ENTRY com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2017-10-03 18:48:10.251
>   !MESSAGE Error creating Liferay plugin project. !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Source
>   'C:\Users\Zerok\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1507049166115'
>   does not exist    at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.createNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:438)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.createNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:1)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:93)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:398)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:362)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source
>   'C:\Users\Zerok\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1507049166115'
>   does not exist    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)    at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.createNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:432)
>     ... 6 more !SUBENTRY 1 com.liferay.ide.project.core 4 0 2017-10-03
>   18:48:10.251 !MESSAGE Source
>   'C:\Users\Zerok\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1507049166115'
>   does not exist !STACK 0 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source
>   'C:\Users\Zerok\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1507049166115'
>   does not exist    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1298)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1191)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1160)    at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.createNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:432)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.PluginsSDKProjectProvider.createNewProject(PluginsSDKProjectProvider.java:1)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.execute(NewLiferayPluginProjectOpMethods.java:93)
>     at
>   com.liferay.ide.project.core.model.NewLiferayPluginProjectOp$Impl.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard.performFinish(SapphireWizard.java:398)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sapphire.ui.forms.swt.SapphireWizard$3.run(SapphireWizard.java:362)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: What do you want to create? In Liferay 7 it is probably possible without the Liferay Plugins SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Liferay Plugins SDK do develop for Liferay 7. Use [Liferay Workspace](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferay-workspace) instead. It allows you to use Maven and Gradle from both the CLI and from Liferay IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To create portlet in the liferay 7/DXP , No requirement of liferay SDK .
You can follow the link below for how to create portlet in liferay 7/DXP .

[Link is for creating portlet in liferay 7](http://proliferay.com/liferay-7-portlet-creation-using-liferay-ide/)